# Задача на JS танк и минное поле

Tags: javascript

Если танк попал на мину, то нужно вывести сообщение «танк повреждён», если это 1-й взрыв, и «танк уничтожен», если это 2-й взрыв. После 2-го взрыва танк считается уничтоженным и прекращает движение.

```
let roadMines = [false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false];
let position = roadMines.indexOf();
let foundMine = false;

for ( let mine of roadMines ) {
    console.log( `Танк переместился на ${++position + 1}` );
    if (mine == true) {
        foundMine = true;
        console.log( 'Танк повреждён' );
        continue;
    }
}

console.log( foundMine ? 'Танк уничтожен' : 'Танк не уничтожен' );
```

Comment: а в чем смысл `let position = roadMines.indexOf();`?

Comment: для того, чтобы получить текущую позицию танка

Comment: Тут ты не получаешь позицию танка, тут ты ищешь значение `undefined` в массиве, и так как у тебя тебя этого значения нет всегда будет -1, поэтому лучше сразу -1 записать

Answer (score 1):

```js
let roadMines = [false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false];
let position = roadMines.indexOf();
let healthPoints = 2;

for ( let mine of roadMines ) {
    console.log( `Танк переместился на ${++position + 1}` );
    if (mine == true) {
        --healthPoints;
        if(healthPoints > 0) console.log( 'Танк повреждён' );
        else {
         console.log( 'Танк уничтожен' );
         break;
        };
    }
}
if(healthPoints > 0 ) console.log( 'Танк превозмог' );
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ЮрийСмекалин слева от ответа галочка